# Apache 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, apache

При переносе с одного сервера на другой сайт перестал работать. Сервер отдает 500 ответ. Причем на этом же сервере есть другие сайты на *php*, которые прекрасно работают.

В логах следующее:

> [Tue Aug 11 20:50:59.040653 2015] [cgi:error] [pid 10354] [client 127.0.0.1:51431] End of script output before headers: php

В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Может cgi запрещён?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, 123 отобразилось. Если проблема в скриптах сайта, почему они нормально работали на предыдущем хостинге?

Comment: Не знаю, может быть это имеет значение. Идентификаторы [pid 10354] в error log записываются всегда с разные.

Comment: @ModaL, нет cgi разрешен

Comment: @alexanderbarakin дело в том, что скрипты почти не редактировались, я даже пробовал делать установку с 0, пытался запустить их из коробки еще до моего вмешательства.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. для начала создайте какой-нибудь тестовый файл типа

   ```
   <?php echo 123;
   ```

   назовите его, например, `test123.php`, поместите в `docroot` сайта и обратитесь к нему из браузера: `http://ваш.сайт/test123.php`.

   если строка `123` отобразится, значит, скорее всего, проблемы в содержимом `php`-скриптов.
2. проблема может возникать, например, потому, что какой-нибудь из загружающихся в самом начале скриптов (`index.php`, какие-нибудь подключаемые конфигурационные файлы) был «криво исправлен» и в него попал «мусор».

   например, какие-нибудь [*bom*-ы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2) в самое начало, или пробелы — **до** стартовых символов `<?php`, или **после** конечных символов `?>`.

   *bom*-ы (и «лишние» пробелы) можно увидеть, например, с помощью команды:

   ```
   $ hexdump -C путь/к/файлу | less
   ```
3. с чего начинается обработка запроса, например, к корню? с `index.php`? добавьте в начале скрипта (после `<?php`) строку вроде

   ```
   echo случайное.число; exit;
   ```

   если получите вывод в виде этого *случайного.числа*, передвигайте эту строку дальше (и глубже — в подключаемые файлы), пока не найдёте «виновника» (файл и строку), который генерирует ошибку.

   чтобы чуть ускорить процесс, после теста на начале файла можно сразу вставить строку в конец, а потом (если будет ошибка) возвращаться «назад» методом «половинного деления».

Comment: +1 за логичное последовательное изложение

Answer (score 0):

Настройки сервера проверяйте.
Файл .htaccess попробуйте удалить или очистить. Вероятно, что в нём может быть проблема.

С подобной ошибкой вот что еще говорят:

> Это может означать, что файл в формате DOS. Такое может случиться, если вы закачали файл по ftp с компьютера под управлением Windows в бинарном режиме. (Вообще не стоит использовать ftp.)

(http://ru.perlmaven.com/perl-cgi-script-with-apache2)