# Wordpress htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, wordpress

Нужно при обращении на url: **/zip-show-services/75566** выдавался контент с **/zip-show-services.html?zip=75566**.

Пробовал что-то типо этого:

```
RewriteRule ^zip-show-services/([0-9]+)?$ /zip-show-services.html&zip=$1 [L]
```

Не помогает, пишет, что страница не найдена.

У Wordpress стоит плагин, который добовляет .html к страницам.

.htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/zip-show-services/([0-9]+)?$ /zip-show-services.html&zip=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: если мой ответ не поможет, приложите, пожалуйста, к вопросу всё содержимое вашего файла.

Comment: файл `zip-show-services.html` действительно существует в корне сайта?

Comment: это динамический url получается. 

Если зайти на http://site/p=198 идет редирект на zip-show-services.html

Comment: я обновил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

вероятно, для начала сто́ит добавить слэш перед `zip-show-services`:

```
RewriteRule ^/zip-show-services/([0-9]+)?$ /zip-show-services.html&zip=$1 [L]
```

---

**обновление**

исходя из добавочной информации, вам надо продолжить обработку правил, чтобы обращение шло к `index.php`.

т.е., оставьте правило там, где оно находится, но уберите флаг `last`:

```
RewriteRule ^/zip-show-services/([0-9]+)?$ /zip-show-services.html&zip=$1
```

Comment: Пробовал уже, все равно не работает

Comment: Страница не найдена. Может нужны какие-то настройки изменить в самом WordPress?

Comment: возможно. вам виднее, что в вашей установке *wordpress* происходит. // я правильно понимаю, что запрос к `/zip-show-services.html?zip=75566` возвращает то, чего вы ожидаете? значит, имеет смысл разобраться, что там внутри `index.php` (и глубже) происходит с таким запросом.

Comment: можно это все как-то отследить?

Comment: можно. например, так, как предложено [в третьем пункте этого ответа](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/442271/178576).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^zip-show-services/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ zip-show-services.html?zip=$1
RewriteRule ^zip-show-services/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ zip-show-services.html?zip=$1
```

Или так

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^zip-show-services/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ zip-show-services.php?zip=$1
RewriteRule ^zip-show-services/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ zip-show-services.php?zip=$1
```

Comment: Этот вопрос не актуален. Новый создан